# Access protected resource from client_credential grant type with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, openid, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to get acclimated with oauth client_credential grant type, to access a protected resource (I'm using this resource server: https://bitbucket.org/hascode/spring-oauth2-example) which works fine given user info existing (implicit flow).

From my understanding, **client_credentials has no user info**, so it's failing on the userinfo endpoint returning a 401

```
2016-07-11 15:19:37.335  INFO 9747 --- [nio-9001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://rain.okta1.com:1802/oauth2/v1/userinfo
2016-07-11 15:19:37.421  INFO 9747 --- [nio-9001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException, 401 Unauthorized
```

I'm also a Spring newbie, so not sure if there are some configs I need to set for this grant type, as I just was going by the tutorial from the same guy: http://www.hascode.com/2016/03/setting-up-an-oauth2-authorization-server-and-resource-provider-with-spring-boot/

There wasn't much config, this is the full resource

```
package com.hascode.tutorial;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class SampleResourceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String securedCall() {
        return "success (id: " + UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase() + ")";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an oauth2 context, you have a client and a resource owner. 
With the implicit grant type, the resource owner is the user who uses your application (the client). The access token you get allow you to retrieve resources owned by the user. 
With the client credentials grant type, the resource owner is the client. So the access token you get allow you to get resources owned by the client.